# For loop cycle order

Tags: python, loops, twitter

I am creating a short script which tweets automatically via twitter API. Besides setting up the API credentials (out of the scope for the question) I import the following library:

```
import os
```

I have set my working directory to be a folder where I have 3 photos. If I run `os.listdir('.')` I get the following list.

```
['Image_1.PNG',
 'Image_2.PNG',
 'Image_3.jpg',]
```

"mylist" is a list of strings, practically 3 tweets.

The code that posts in Twitter automatically looks like that:

```
for image in os.listdir('.'):
    for num in range(len(mylist)):
        api.update_with_media(image, mylist[num])
```

The code basically assigns to the first image a tweet and posts. Then to the same image the second tweet and posts. Again first image - third tweet. Then it continues the cycle to second and third image altogether 3*3 9 times/posts.

However what I want to achieve is to take the first image with the first tweet and post. Then take second image with second tweet and post. Third image - third tweet. Then I want to run the cycle one more time: 1st image - 1st tweet, 2nd image - 2nd tweet ...etc.

Comment: Please clarify your last request "Then I want to repeat that, say, one more time from the beginning."

Comment: Edited. Basically I want to run twice the described behavior i.e. 1st image - 1st tweet, 2nd image - 2nd tweet..... etc.

Comment: Are there always the same number of pictures and tweets?

Comment: Yes always same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip` to iterate through two (or more) collections in parallel

```
for tweet, image in zip(mylist, os.listdir('.')):
    api.update_with_media(image, tweet)
```

To repeat it more times, you can put this cycle inside another `for`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the length of os.listdir('.')  and mylist are equal:

```
length = len(mylist) # If len(os.listdir('.')) is greater than len(mylist),
# replace mylist with os.listdir('.')

imageList = os.listdir('.')
iterations = 2 # The number of time you want this to run
for i in range(0,iterations):
    for x in range(0, length):
        api.update_with_media(imageList[x], mylist[num])
```